# joomla site not downloading google font, why?

Tags: joomla, fonts

I created a website based on Joomla and I use google fonts in it, i.e. in the head part of the document I have:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Merriweather+Sans:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and I see it in source of the page, when I browse to the web site.

In my windows xp underwhich I programmed it is working sure because I downloaded the fonts and installed, to do design under photoshop! 
Browsing it to mobile phone or my other OS (windows 8, etc.) font will not appear!

What could be the reason please?

**Edit:**
I already added CORS header in joomla too! Still not working. I have @import(...) of the font correctly in my css. All spelling is ok and all is working in the windows system where I have the font installed. Why not working / downloading in other OS/browsers, remains a mystery to me!

Comment: This is going to sound silly - but are you referencing it appropriately in the CSS?

Show us the CSS code you're using for it, show us the HTML element you want it applied to and link us the HEAD for the document please.  I don't believe you should be worrying about CORS

Comment: sure, please have a look, this is the web site I created: http://oraclelegalservices.ca/

Comment: I almost always find it works best to put the google fonts call at the very end of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cross check the name of the font in your CSS file with its name in the Google fonts page

Comment: Thanks. Not solving the issue: I checked and all correct because I exactly coppied the font name when created the joomla template. Also, if spelling is a problem, then it should not work anywhere but it is working in the windows OS where I have the font installed.